# How does one run script(API) on Gatsby/React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, gatsby

I added map API script to index.js class return:

```
<script>
  var mapContainer = document.getElementById('map'),  
      mapOption = {
          center: new kakao.maps.LatLng(37.56591, 126.97894), 
          level: 4, 
          mapTypeId : kakao.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }; 

  var map = new kakao.maps.Map(mapContainer, mapOption); 

</script>
```

It gives two errors:

> '}' expected.(line 4 ":")
>   Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or `&rbrace;`? (line 7 "}")

It is supposed to work in html. Isn't react supposed to return html attributes? I once thought maybe it doesn't accept script, but the following code doesn't have syntax error:

```
<script src="https://dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey=3199e8f198aff9d5aff73000faae6608"></script>
```

*Using React’s dangerouslySetInnerHTML attribute did not work too. It does fix syntax error, but doesn't show my map:

https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/custom-html/

* doesn't fix syntax error

Here is the full `index.js` code:

```
import React from "react"

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
  return (
    <div style={{ color: `purple` }}>
      <p>Welcome to donghwankim.com!</p>
      <p>Powered by Gatsby</p>
      <div id="map" style={{width:'500px', height:'400px'}}></div>
      <script src="https://dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey=3199e8f198aff9d5aff73000faae6608"></script>
      <script>
        var mapContainer = document.getElementById('map'), // 지도를 표시할 div 
          mapOption = {
            center: new kakao.maps.LatLng(37.56591, 126.97894), // 지도의 중심좌표
            level: 4, // 지도의 확대 레벨
            mapTypeId : kakao.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // 지도종류
          }; 

        // 지도를 생성한다 
        var map = new kakao.maps.Map(mapContainer, mapOption); 

       </script>

    </div>
  )}
}
```

original html file I tried and confirmed working:(forgot adding https: and hid key. very sorry.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>다음 지도 API</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width:1000px;height:500px;"></div>

    <script src="https://dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey=3199e8f198aff9d5aff73000faae6608"></script>
    <script>
        var mapContainer = document.getElementById('map'), // 지도를 표시할 div
            mapOption = {
                center: new kakao.maps.LatLng(37.56591, 126.97894), // 지도의 중심좌표
                level: 4, // 지도의 확대 레벨
                mapTypeId : kakao.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // 지도종류
            };

        // 지도를 생성한다
        var map = new kakao.maps.Map(mapContainer, mapOption);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post more of the relevant code? There are many ways to do use client side packages. Have a look [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/using-client-side-only-packages/).

Comment: I uploaded full code, which is itself very short. @apena

Comment: You said it is suposed to work in html. Do you have a working example using your api key without react? When I try to write a code pen using `//dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey=3199e8f1xx` I get the error `{"errorType":"AccessDeniedError","message":"wrong appKey(3199e8f1xx) format"}`

Comment: Thank you very much for actually running the code for me. I didn't expect it. I uploaded workable code and confirmed it's working in its original html form(I uploaded at last)

Comment: Check your network panel in your browser when you run the site and see if the script is getting loaded. I was getting a 401 (unauthorized). when trying to run it on codepen.

Comment: also update your question to let people know the error is during the `gatsby build` process.

Comment: The issue is on the kakao side. You can hide your api key again if you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

```
<script
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `
          var mapContainer = document.getElementById('map'), // 지도를 표시할 div 
          mapOption = {
            center: new kakao.maps.LatLng(37.56591, 126.97894), // 지도의 중심좌표
            level: 4, // 지도의 확대 레벨
            mapTypeId : kakao.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // 지도종류
          }; 

        // 지도를 생성한다 
        var map = new kakao.maps.Map(mapContainer, mapOption); 
        `,
  }}
/>
```

Comment: It does remove syntax error, but it doesn't work correctly for some reason.

Comment: I bet you need to whitelist (from the kakao side) the domain you are using the script on.

Comment: Why is it then, that it works on plain html but not on gatsby?

Comment: @Bingkongmaster What is your problem? What do you see in the console? How doesn't it work?

Comment: When I run the script on plain index.html file, I see a full map. When I insert the script to dangerouslySetInnerHTML, I see no map.